# Domain and subdomain .htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I need make two different redirects in `.htaccess`.

On one website: `example.com` is created alias `user.example.com` (same code for two domains).

I need to write two redirects

`user.example.com` -> `user.example.com/login`

and second one

`example.com` -> `www.example.com` (versions without www to version with www) including subpages (excluding `user.example.com` - not www version)

all redirects with https protocol

only one redirect works fine, but with the second one together it fails.

```
RewriteEngine On

## RewriteRule ^user.example.com https://user.example.com/login [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^user\.example\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://user.example.com/login [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried so far?

Comment: i shared my rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^user\.example\.com/ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*) https://user.example.com/login [L,R]
> ```

This will result in a redirect-loop, since it redirects *everything* (including `/login` itself) to `/login`.

If you only want to redirect the document root, then you should change the `RewriteRule` *pattern* from `^(.*)` to `^$` (an *empty* URL-path).

The other redirect is "OK".

You should clear your browser cache before testing.